# create .desktop for portable executable (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: .desktop

Is there any GUI way to create the ${HOME}/Desktop file for any portable application (not installed as package) in Ubuntu 22.04?
I know there are answers how to create the .desktop file manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for "desktop launcher" has been helpful for me in the past in looking for apps like this. [One such example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries#Tools), `alacarte`, is in the Ubuntu repositories, and searching for "desktop launcher" on e.g. Flathub gives these results among the top ones, all of which would fit the bill for adding a new custom entry to your menus (thereby creating the .desktop file):

https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.ryonakano.pinit

https://flathub.org/apps/page.codeberg.libre_menu_editor.LibreMenuEditor

https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.alexkdeveloper.desktop-files-creator

And as usual [the Arch Wiki on this topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries#Tools) is helpful too.

Comment: Thank you for sources as well